# React router returning blank page when accessed directly from browser address bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a react app with 2 levels of navigation using a side bar and a header. When I navigate using the links everything works fine. But when I try to enter the address directly in the browser address-bar. the levels work but the headers do not. For the headers, the whole page disappears and I see a blank page.

I am new to react, so would greatly appreciate any advice on what I might be doing wrong.

The app looks like below

**Level1**
               **Header1**   Header2   Header3
              This is Level1/Header1
Level2
Level3

The Routes that I have defined are as follows:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="Level1" component={Level1}>
    <Route path="Header1" component={Page1}/>
    <Route path="Header2" component={Page2}/>
    <Route path="Header3" component={Page3}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="Level2" component={Level2}/>
  <Route path="Level3" component={Level3}/>
</Route>
```

The code for the SideBar component is :

```
export default class SideBar extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <nav className="nav navbar-default">
          <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/Level1">Level1</Link></li>
            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/Level2">Level2</Link></li>
            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/Level3">Level3</Link></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

The code for the header component is :

```
export default class Header extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ><Link activeClassName="active" to="/Level1/Header1">Header1</Link></li>
        <li ><Link activeClassName="active" to="/Level1/Header2">Header2</Link></li>
        <li ><Link activeClassName="active" to="/Level1/Header3">Header3</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The Level1 component is the where the header is used as follows:

```
export default class Level1 extends React.Component{

        render(){
            return(
                <div >
                    <Header/>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you using the `Header` component? It's not in your routes.

Comment: And if you could add some images of how the page looks in `/`, `/Level1`, `/Level1/Header1` and `/Level2` will be useful.

Comment: The header component is only on the Level1 page. I am updating the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to replicate your code, [this is the far I can get](https://jsfiddle.net/byoigres/ba10p15o/1/).

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Level1} />
      <Route path="Level1" component={Level1}>
        <IndexRoute component={Page1} />
        <Route path="Header1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="Header2" component={Page2} />
        <Route path="Header3" component={Page3} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="Level2" component={Level2} />
      <Route path="Level3" component={Level3} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I saw your fiddle and it looks ok. My problem is only occuring on the browser when I enter the address directly or refresh the page when I am on any of the header pages (e.g. Header 1 in your fiddle).

Comment: I figured this is because of server rendering not being enabled on the server. have fixed it by rendering the app on the server.